# Feeding Tempo to DAW

Tags: drums, tempo, ableton-live, logic-pro

Basically, I have a drummer and I am a Keyboard player from whom I wanted to feed the tempo to the system and thereby play arpeggios and other things which are required, which is very important for me. Is there any best way to do it. DO you want me to have a man keep feeding the tempo, in frequent intervals(right before my arpeggios have to play)? or is there any better way to achieve it?

My drumset is acoustic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MajBoredom said, the simplest way is to sync everyone to the tempo of the DAW. But both [Ableton](https://www.ableton.com/answers/tap-tempo) and [Logic Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13221?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) both have "tap-tempo" which lets you tap in the tempo in manually. You just need to give it a couple taps of the BPM you want and it will detect the speed. You can map a keyboard key to do this, or even a pedal or anything that can send MIDI data. So you can tap out the tempo in the beginning of the track, then adjust it as the band plays.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the drummer headphones with a click track to play to so that the drummer stays in sync with your DAW - that might be easier than trying to get the computer to adapt to the band as they change tempo slightly over the course of the song.